# Datatables - How to modify colors of "Show n entries"

Tags: css, datatables

I am looking to customize colors for "Show n entries" dropdown select list.

I am trying to find which classes shall I override to change the blue border of both select and options and the background of option being hover.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blue border of the dropdown is not specific to datatables. But its of the tag `<select>`. If you see library file of jquery datatables, you can see that it uses `<select>` to show dropdown options. So its not possible to change the background blue color of select options.

However, we can use any other third party  library  which has options of changing the color in a way that we want.

This can be integrated into datatables by adding below configuration to your datatables configuration.

```
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": 'Display <select>'+
          '<option value="10"><div>10</div></option>'+
          '<option value="20">20</option>'+
          '<option value="30">30</option>'+
          '<option value="40">40</option>'+
          '<option value="50">50</option>'+
          '<option value="-1">All</option>'+
          '</select> records'
      }
```

Replace your third party  library within lengthMenu property to get the desired css for dropdown. Note that you might need to handle dropdown select event and appropriately filter search results.